# How to revoke a user's google refresh token?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

I let users connect their google calendar account to allow their patients to make appointments with them.

How can I revoke a user's refresh token using node js and the google calendar api? Sometimes users request that we no longer have access to their accounts. I want to fulfill their wish.

Here's the code I'm using

```
const {tokens} = await oauth2Client.getToken(request.query.code);
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
   access_token: tokens.access_token,
}); // use the new auth client with the access_token

let {data} = await oauth2.userinfo.get({
   auth: oauth2Client,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the revokeToken method. It requires you pass a specific accessToken to the method: [oauth2client.ts#L801](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/src/auth/oauth2client.ts#L801)

Or there is the revokeCredentials method which accepts no arguments, and revokes the access token currently configured in the OAuth2 instance: [oauth2client.ts#L827](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/src/auth/oauth2client.ts#L827)

It may sound strange that i am telling you to use an access token to revoke a refresh token but if you read [tokenrevoke](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke) you will see that what it actually does is remove the users consent to your application.

Once the users consent is removed refresh tokens are automatically revoked.   so an access token is needed to call the api end point to revoke the refresh token.

Comment: But don't access token expire after a day or so?

Comment: Access tokens expire after one hour.   Use your refresh token to request a new access token. Then call the revoke endpoint with the access token.  This will then revoke the access the user granted to your application.   The refresh token will then no longer work.

Comment: I get an error "invalid token" when I use the access token. What should I do?

Comment: Request a new one its probably expired.

Comment: Do I have to make the user go through oauth again?

Comment: yes thats the only way to request a new token